# Python Exception Handling Ignore Corresponding Line Data

Tags: python

```
try:
f3 = open("c:\\temp\\MP11Data1.txt")
lines = f3.readlines()
for line in lines:
    k1 = line
    
num1 = float(k1)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

If you accidentally convert text file data and receive a ValueError error, you attempt to create an exception process that ignores the data (string) in the row of the text file, but the data is not ignored and output. What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: IndentationError ...

Comment: There is no output in your code. Beside the IndentationError that makes it impossible to run your code at all. Posting code that is different from what you execute makes no sense - we do not even see where you print anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think num1 in your code was last value, It's outside loop for.

you try this.

```
f3 = open("c:\\temp\\MP11Data1.txt")
lines = f3.readlines()
array_float = []
for line in lines:
    k1 = line
    try:
       num1 = float(k1)
       array_float.append(num1)
    except ValueError:
       pass
print(array_float)
```

Comment: Then what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Oh, thanks to your feedback, I succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: If answer is correct,please vote answer, thanks. :-)